# Intercept the creation of all scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to add a destroy listener to all my scopes so I can do some custom cleanup things. I don't want to add $scope.$on('$destroy') to all my controllers so I found the $provide.decorator method and tried this:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$provide', function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$rootScope', ['$delegate', decorateScope]);

        function decorateScope(scope) {
            var oldNew = scope.$new.bind(scope);

            scope.$new = function() {
                var newScope = oldNew(arguments);
                console.log('Scope created');

                newScope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    console.log('Scope destroyed');
                });

                return decorateScope(newScope);
            };

            return scope;
        }
    }
]);
```

this will recursively intercept the creation of all scopes. The console logs the creation and destruction of all scopes. but does not work as before, the scope inheritance chain seems somehow broken.

How could this be solved?